# ACF Repeater field doesn't output images

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF repeater plugin on my wordpress site to generate simple gallery. this si the code in my tempalte file:

```
<?php if( have_rows('gallery') ): ?>
<ul class="slides">                              
  <?php while( have_rows('gallery') ): the_row();                        
  // vars
  $image = get_sub_field('gallery_images');                          
  ?>    
<li class="slide">                                   
  <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt=""/>               
</li>                                
<?php endwhile; ?>                               
</ul>                                
<?php endif; ?>
```

And this is html output on frontpage:

```
<ul class="slides">                                 
 <li class="slide"><img alt="" src="h"></li>
</ul>
```

The image src outputs "h"... I have double checked and the sub_field “slider_images” is set to be Image URL. 
I copied the code from documentation, didn't change anything.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're outputting the URL from the ACF directly, I don't think you need the `echo $image['url']` anymore. `echo $image` will do.

You should use `while(have_rows('gallery_images'))` and `get_sub_field('url')` then `echo $image`

Comment: Thank you! indeed ['url'] was not needed and removing it fixed the issue! stackoverflow is the best :)